# Big voltage drop across MOSFET with LED strip load

Tags: microcontroller, led, mosfet, led-strip, voltage

I'm trying to power up a [Giderwell RGBCCT LED strip](https://www.amazon.co.uk/GIDERWEL-RGBCCT-Changing-Waterproof-Flexible/dp/B07SS6XTZT) using ESP32 (a 3.3V microcontroller) with the help of an IRL540N MOSFET.

My circuit looks like this:

[image: Circuit]

(sorry for the amateurish/nonstandard diagram, I'm not educated in EE)

R1 is a simple pull-down resistor to ensure the gate is low while the chip is powered off/booting. 
I actually have 5 MOSFETs driving 5 channels of an RGBCCT strip, but everything is the same if only one channel is powered.

**My problem:** When the gate is high and there is no load, I measure 12V across the drain and source terminals of the MOSFET (as expected). However, when the LED strip is connected, this voltage drops significantly, to 6-8V, depending on the MOSFET and channel I'm measuring. The LEDs are also much darker than when connected to +12V and GND directly.

This is a small segment of an LED strip containing 6 LEDs per channel, and by spec should peak at 300mA for the whole segment, so approx. 60mA per channel.

What could be causing this? I'm using a perfboard - is my soldering to blame? (It's pretty atrocious, this is my first soldering project.) Maybe I cooked the MOSFETs while soldering, causing them to not be able to deliver the current? Is the 3.3V logic level too low to fully activate the MOSFET? The datasheet suggests a max 2.0V threshold and ~10A of continuous current at 3.0V gate-to-source, which should be plenty. I might be missing another parameter though.

I measured the resistance from GND to the source pin on the MOSFET, and from the drain pin of the MOSFET to the cathode pad at the end of the strip, and it's around 0.3 ohm. If it matters, I used AWG 20 wire (0.5mm²) to connect everything, joined by soldering on the perfboard.

**Update:** I measured the drain-source resistance on the MOSFETs while their gates were high. Most of them have around ~20 ohms, give or take, while one has 3.9 ohms, but even across that one the voltage is ~9V, a 3V drop. For one with 25 ohms, the drop is 6V. I'm even more confused now as the resistances are different and the drops are not proportional to the resistance...

Comment: When the strip should be powered up: what v_gate do you measure?

Comment: It sounds like the MOSFET is operating in saturation mode and not linear mode ("fully ON").  What gate-to-source voltage do you measure when the microcontroller is outputting a logic HIGH signal?   What is the time duration when you turn ON the MOSFET (microseconds, milliseconds, seconds, etc.)?

Comment: If you can, please edit your question and provide the name of the manufacturer and the model number of the LED strip you are using. Alternatively, provide the name of the distributor (e.g., Sparkfun, Digi-Key, etc.) and the distributor's part number for the LED strip you are using.

Comment: @geomaster, You asked: " Is the 3.3V logic level too low to fully activate the MOSFET?" The answer is most likely yes.

Comment: Are you able to disconnect the MOSFET gate from your ESP32 and apply a higher voltage to it, such as 6V from a 10K+10K potential divider connected across your 12V supply? Then you could see if it's a good MOSFET with too low a drive voltage or a damaged MOSFET.

Comment: @tariksbl Measuring 3.23V across gate-source pins of the MOSFET.

Comment: @JimFischer Gate-to-source voltage is around 3.23V. Not understanding your second question - I have the chip set to output a logic 1 on the pin all the time for testing purposes. I've kept it on for ~20 minutes and nothing changed. I added an Amazon link for the LED strip to my question.

Comment: @TonyM I'll try that - I'm powering the chip through an 12V->5V USB voltage regulator (the chip has another regulator to 3.3V but it cannot take 12V) so I'll try connecting the gate to that and report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a logic-level MOSFET rated for <= 3.3V gate drive to make that work. You have a MOSFET rated for 4V gate drive according to the [datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irl540npbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153565fc2a62567) so you're not completely driving it 'on'.

It's a bit surprising it's that bad, if the part is genuine. Measure Vgs directly at the MOSFET, from gate to source. If there is excessive resistance in the source circuit it could be taking away the already inadequate Vgs voltage.

Comment: That would have been my first suspicion, too.  But the figures on page 3 seem to imply it should work reasonably well for quite a bit more current the the OP is trying to switch with 3 volts on the gate.

Comment: @ChrisStratton  Those are only typical curves not guaranteed, but I agree it still seems too little, as I said above. So I suspect it's either not getting 3.3V-ish or the MOSFET is not what is claimed, despite the fact it's not guaranteed to work, and therefore bad practice to use it in this application.

Comment: Thanks! Vgs directly at the MOSFET is 3.23V. Bummer, I saw this MOSFET suggested in forums for Arduino Due which also uses 3.3V logic, so I figured it's a safe bet. How do I find a MOSFET that is guaranteed to turn on at 3.3V? What do I look for in the datasheet? Am I right in assuming that this is as much juice I'll be able to get from the ones I have i.e. attaching more of the LED strip will just drop more voltage and won't get any brighter?

Comment: Where did you get the MOSFETs from?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I was only able to find them in my country from a seller on a personals website, probably resold from AliExpress or similar. The seller seemed reputable based on the reviews from other buyers, though. Here's a photo of the MOSFETs: https://i.imgur.com/JJSNEfe.jpg. However, I also soldered them with a non-temperature-controlled 40W iron that heats to 482° C by spec, and for quite a bit of time because I couldn't do it quickly enough. (I know, this is very dumb. I've switched to a new iron since.) Could this have altered the properties?

Comment: More likely the parts are fake.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thanks, I'll try a more legitimate distribution channel from now on. Should I get different ones, then? Do you have a suggestion? How do I figure out on the datasheet if the MOSFET is suitable for a 3.3V drive, if the graphs are only typical characteristics and shouldn't be relied upon?

Comment: Okay, look at the Rds(on) guaranteed numbers. There is a Vgs associated with each. You want a MOSFET with acceptable Rds(on) at your drive voltage or a bit less. Keep in mind Rds(on) increases about 50% when the MOSFET is very hot so don't call it too close.  For only 300mA you could use an [AO3400A](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Alpha%20&%20Omega/AO3400A_ds.pdf) with 2.5V drive it has Rds(on) < 48m ohms, so power dissipated will be I^2*R = 4mW which is  very low.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thank you. It looks like AO3400A will do the trick. I actually plan on having 3 of these 300mA strands, so 900mA peak total, but this is if all channels are 100% on all the time, which can be restricted in software because there's no need (two of the channels are white). But even at 900mA and 50% higher Rds(on), I'm calculating ~58mW, which should still be small, right?

Comment: Yes, it should be okay. Add a 20K-50K resistor from gate to source since if it floats into linear region that little part will burn up quickly.

Comment: Actually, 900mA is for 5 channels, and one MOSFET is for one channel, so it should handle just up to 180mA. Thanks for the help - just ordered them - this time from an actual electronics store :)